# why i am getting error while using resolve in angular js?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-directive, angularjs-scope, ionic-framework

I am trying to use resolve  .Mean I need to get data from service before loading the controller and view .I found some line how to use resolve .

I an not getting error in my project when I remove resolve statement

```
.state('a', {
      url: "/a",
      templateUrl: "a.html",
          controller: 'a',
          // resolve:{
          //   messsage:function(testservice){
          //     return testservice.getdata();
          //   }
          //}
      })
```

when I uncomment the resolve statement I got this error

```
**Error: [$rootScope:infdig] 10 $digest() iterations reached. Aborting!
Watchers fired in the last 5 iterations: []
http://errors.angularjs.org/1.3.13/$rootScope/infdig?p0=10&p1=%5B%5D
    at REGEX_STRING_REGEXP (ionic.bundle.js:8762)
    at Scope.promises.$get.Scope.$digest (ionic.bundle.js:22980)
    at Scope.promises.$get.Scope.$apply (ionic.bundle.js:23205)
    at done (ionic.bundle.js:18358)
    at completeRequest (ionic.bundle.js:18548)
    at XMLHttpRequest.requestLoaded (ionic.bundle.js:18489)(anonymous function) @ ionic.bundle.js:20306jqNodes.$get @ ionic.bundle.js:17256promises.$get.Scope.$apply @ ionic.bundle.js:23207done @ ionic.bundle.js:18358completeRequest @ ionic.bundle.js:18548requestLoaded @ ionic.bundle.js:18489
ionic.bundle.js:8762 Uncaught Error: [$rootScope:infdig] 10 $digest() iterations reached. Aborting!
Watchers fired in the last 5 iterations: []
http://errors.angularjs.org/1.3.13/$rootScope/infdig?p0=10&p1=%5B%5DREGEX_STRING_REGEXP @ ionic.bundle.js:8762promises.$get.Scope.$digest @ ionic.bundle.js:22980promises.$get.Scope.$apply @ ionic.bundle.js:23205done @ ionic.bundle.js:18358completeRequest @ ionic.bundle.js:18548requestLoaded @ ionic.bundle.js:18489
ionic.bundle.js:20306 Error: [$rootScope:infdig] 10 $digest() iterations reached. Aborting!
Watchers fired in the last 5 iterations: []
http://errors.angularjs.org/1.3.13/$rootScope/infdig?p0=10&p1=%5B%5D
    at REGEX_STRING_REGEXP (ionic.bundle.js:8762)
    at Scope.promises.$get.Scope.$digest (ionic.bundle.js:22980)
    at Scope.promises.$get.Scope.$apply (ionic.bundle.js:23205)
    at done (ionic.bundle.js:18358)
    at completeRequest (ionic.bundle.js:18548)
    at XMLHttpRequest.requestLoaded**
```

here is my code
http://plnkr.co/edit/fk7IGcYlDfZasWqzy31S?p=preview

I am trying to load data from service before using in controller and before loading to view

Comment: are you using `angular.min.js` or the full `angular.js` on your index page script call?

Comment: I have created similar example which shows resolve http://plnkr.co/edit/iY0sCnM5dzvassz2k0KL?p=preview

Answer (score 1):

Use the good syntax for your service

```
factory('testservice', ['$http',
    function testservice($http) {
```

Fetch the data in your controller :

```
$scope.data = testservice.getdata();
```

The plnk :
http://plnkr.co/edit/2EskRAzVPo8lhXyaLFuy?p=preview

Then you should consider backing your data in the service so you call `$http.get("data.json")`one time.

Comment: I don't want to fetch data in controller i want to use resolve.

Comment: Thanks for answering how to use this data in controller ..? mean I want to call service using resolve and use son data in controller

Comment: your plunker is correct but how to use in controller the service data

Comment: .controller('a', function($scope, $stateParams, $state, $ionicHistory, message) {